# Spring boot application not able to access the third party REST API on Heroku platform which is accepting request specific to Indian IP addresses

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, heroku, spring-rest

I have a Java Spring Boot application that exposes REST endpoints and deployed on Heroku free service.

The problem I am facing is that I am calling another third party REST API from the controller class and that API takes only request that comes from Indian IP address.

On Heroku, the URL I got is sending an outbound request from the US or EU server because of which I am not getting the response returning from my application.

Can someone help if there is an option to call that third party from the spring boot application that I have deployed on the Heroku platform?

What exactly I need to do to achieve this?

**Note: I can not whitelist the source IP address on the third-party REST API side.**

Answer (score 1):

Trying CoWin,
Eh ?

If so, you can't do so on Heroku. They don't allow any IP masking as you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to access the COWIN public Api's